# How can I access an array inside a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash within an array:

```
values = {}
values.merge!(name => {
  "requested_amount" => @specific_last_pending_quota.requested_amount,
  "granted" => @specific_last_pending_quota.granted,
  "pending_final" => pending_final
})
@o_requests[request.receiving_organization][request.program_date][:data] = values
```

I send it to the view and then when I get it so:

```
= quota[:data].inspect
# {"theme"=>{"requested_amount"=>2, "granted"=>false, "pending_final"=>0}}
```

I want to fetch the object like this:

```
= quota[:data]["theme"].inspect
```

But I got this error

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

Comment: This should work. There's probably something you are not showing.

Comment: Yes its really weird!. I change the name var to a hash name like :component so when I do in the view this :-- > = quota[:data][:component] I still getting: can't convert Symbol into Integer.
The hash output it's : {:component=>{"requested_amount"=>1, "granted"=>false, "pending_final"=>5}}

Comment: What's the output when you do: `quota[:data].class` ?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using and what is the value of `name` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `quota[:data]` may return array of hash

Try:

```
= quota[:data][0]["theme"]
```

Here I tried case to get same error and check:

```
 > h[:data]
 #=> [{"theme"=>{"requested_amount"=>2, "granted"=>false, "pending_final"=>0}}] 
 > h[:data]["theme"]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb):10:in `[]'
    from (irb):10
    from /home/ggami/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
 > h[:data][0]["theme"]
 #=> {"requested_amount"=>2, "granted"=>false, "pending_final"=>0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. i changed the structure of my array for get the similar as you but when I do this: ---> = quota[:data][0].inspect I get: {"theme"=>{"requested_amount"=>2, "granted"=>false, "pending_final"=>0}} and when I do this: --->                = quota[:data][0]['theme'].inspect I got can't convert String into Integer

Comment: Finally the problem it was that some hashes was coming empty :) but  this solution it was the best for me thanks!

Comment: Good to know it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try convert it to proper hash I guess it should work fine.

```
values = {}
 values.merge!(name => {:requested_amount => @specific_last_pending_quota.requested_amount, :granted => @specific_last_pending_quota.granted, :pending_final => pending_final})

@o_requests[request.receiving_organization][request.program_date][:data] = values
```

Comment: I change like this but f.e the output of quota[:data].inspect  it's: {"theme"=>{:requested_amount=>1}} and if I want to do something like : quota[:data]['theme'] or quota[:data].each or whatever throw an error